# Why speed difference of update sql in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I am currently using the UPDATE in C# with SQL Server.

I have around 20 UPDATE SQL statements that I've written, and I've combined them into a single string to execute them all at once.

However, I've noticed a significant difference in performance depending on how I handle variables.

1.

```
string sql = @"
UPDATE T1 SET COL1= @VALUE1, COL2= @VALUE1 , COL3= '2023-08-22 13:44:40' WHERE KEY1=@KEY1_1 AND KEY2_1 = @KEY2 AND KEY3 = @KEY3_1 AND KEY4 = @KEY4_1 AND KEY5 = @KEY5_1;
UPDATE T2 SET COL1= '2023-08-22 13:44:40', COL2= '2023-08-22 13:44:40' WHERE KEY1=@KEY1_1 AND KEY2 = @KEY2_1 AND KEY3 = @KEY3_1  ; 

UPDATE T1 SET COL1= @VALUE2, COL2= @VALUE2 , COL3= '2023-08-22 13:44:40' WHERE KEY1=@KEY1_2 AND KEY2 = @KEY2_2 AND KEY3 = @KEY3_2 AND KEY4 = @KEY4_2 AND KEY5 = @KEY5_2;
UPDATE T2 SET COL1= '2023-08-22 13:44:40', COL2= '2023-08-22 13:44:40' WHERE KEY1=@KEY1_2 AND KEY2 = @KEY2_2 AND KEY3 = @KEY3_2  ; 
...
...
";
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> items in dic) {
    // All columns to be used are nVarChar.
    cmd.Parameters.Add(items.Key, SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = items.Value;
}
```

2. 

```
string value1 = "'test'"; // value , key example
string sql = $@"
UPDATE T1 SET COL1= {value1}, COL2= {value1} , COL3= '2023-08-22 13:44:40' WHERE KEY1={key1_1} AND KEY2 = {key2_1} AND KEY3 = {key3_1} AND KEY4 = {key4_1} AND KEY5 = {key5_1};
UPDATE T2 SET COL1= '2023-08-22 13:44:40', COL2= '2023-08-22 13:44:40' WHERE KEY1={key1_1} AND KEY2 = {key2_1} AND KEY3 = {key3_1}  ; 

UPDATE T1 SET COL1= {value2}, COL2= {value2} , COL3= '2023-08-22 13:44:40' WHERE KEY1={key1_2} AND KEY2 = {key2_2} AND KEY3 = {key3_2} AND KEY4 = {key4_2} AND KEY5 = {key5_2};
UPDATE T2 SET COL1= '2023-08-22 13:44:40', COL2= '2023-08-22 13:44:40' WHERE KEY1={key1_2} AND KEY2 = {key2_2} AND KEY3 = {key3_2}  ; 
...
...
";
```

In the first method, I parameterize the queries using cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue, while in the second method, I directly embed variables into the SQL queries.

When I execute these 20 SQL statements together, the first method takes over 20 seconds, whereas the second method completes in less than 2 seconds.
Even when I use the OPTION (RECOMPILE) option for the first method, the performance difference remains significant.

I've heard before that using SqlCommand.Parameters is the correct approach. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you leave key4 and key5 out of the first query?

Comment: The 5 keys are the unique means to distinguish rows, so they cannot be removed.

Comment: `AddWithValue` isn't great to use, not the least of which is because of its type-guessing behaviours. What happens if you use one of the proper [`SqlParameterCollection.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add) overloads and specify correct data types, lengths/scales/precisions?

Comment: I tried changing `AddWithValue` to `cmd.Parameters.Add(items.Key, SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = items.Value;` but the speed remains unchanged.

Comment: What is the `CREATE TABLE`? Are the columns definitely `NVarChar` rather than `VarChar`? And what do the fast and slow execution plans look like?

Comment: The actual table is quite complex, and that table is just an example. 
However, I added all the KEYs of that table to where condition. Also, all the columns I use as variables are `NVarchar`. To clarify further, I've modified the example in the content.

Comment: @rhrhgut If you include the size value in the SQL parameter, it means that SQL Server does not need to make a new execution plan for each different length of the parameter, which might help.

Comment: @rhrhgut - Your second approach is prone to SQL injection attacks so it should be avoided even if it is faster.

Comment: @Enigmativity I am aware that there is a risk of injection when directly specifying variables in the query.
However, if I ask users to wait for 20 seconds when the task can be completed within 2 seconds, they might kick me out of frustration.

Comment: @rhrhgut - What does the generated SQL look like?

Comment: @ Andrew Morton - After seeing your comment, I tried set the parameter size, but the speed remained unchanged.

Comment: @Enigmativity
 The actual SQL is no different from examples 1 and 2. The only difference lies in the table names and column names. In order to update 20 rows from 2 tables, the queries are combined into a single string and executed together. Furthermore, since the values being updated are different for each row, the use of `IN` is not viable.

The reason for executing them all at once is due to the network firewall causing slow DB connections, thereby aiming to minimize the frequency of connections.

Comment: what do the fast and slow execution plans look like?

Comment: @Martin Smith  
I executed two examples, captured the query through Profiler, and then examined the execution plan by running it on the actual database.

When I manually entered the variables into the query, all the keys specified in the where clause were listed in the Index Seek's seek predicates. However, when I used SqlCommand.Parameters, only one index appeared in the seek predicates, and it was evident that it took a long time. Honestly, I'm not sure about the cause.

Comment: It could be different cardinality estimation but if you still see this with `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` then the cardinality estimation should be the same. So I go back to thinking that at least one of the parameters is of the wrong datatype for the column and you are getting an implicit cast

Comment: @Martin I realized that one table had all index columns as nvarchar, while another table had a mix of varchar. After accurately specifying the column types using cmd.Parameters.Add(), the difference in speed disappeared. I'm amazed by my own foolishness, and I think if it weren't for you, I might have never noticed it. Thank you so much!